# Echarts custom label with icon

Tags: angular, label, echarts

Is it possible to do this in eCharts? I need to add this Label in addition to the current value.

[image]

I managed to almost reproduce the image above. But I need to change the Symbol according to what is returned in the Label and change its color to green or red.

In the documentation there is no option to use a function in Symbol, only String.

[image]

This is the result that I managed to do.

[image]

That is the complete code.

[image]

And that's the error if I use Function on Symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Please take a look on [example](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=x1QFWo7IIB), this seems to be what you need.

[image]

Comment: This is a very tragic story... Can't hold back my tears. What else to do if no one has shown their code? Do you seriously think that there are telepaths? They don't exist and for solve you problem you need to show the problem code.

Comment: See working example with latest lib version — http://jsfiddle.net/dgoh1mke/

Comment: This is some kind of joke? How I can copy the code and run locally? And the error as I see not in JS, this is TypeScript error. The problem out of scope Echarts and JavaScript. OK I will try to fix but without original code It can be complicated.

Comment: Great! Are you confused by the problem with the symbol? How to choose the `Up` or `Down`? If yes, then see the following answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Echarts `symbol` like a `formatter` can getting the function that returning `path://...`. Therefore you need to check the value/percent on positive/negative and return the corresponding arrow: `symbol: (...params) => { ... return 'path://....' }`.

---

But in your case I would suggest another option to avoid code complexity: generate already complete series to insert into chart instead calculation in realtime.

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

  var upPath = "path://M88 264l31 31 123-122 0 268 44 0 0-269 123 124 32-32-177-176Z";
  var dwPath = "path://M441 264l-32-31-123 123 0-268-44 0 0 268-123-123-31 31 176 176Z";

  var option = {
    // ... all necessary options

    series: [],  // <------ leave blank

    // ... something else if you need
  };

  function calculatePercent( ... ){ ... }
  // ... another utility functions

  var chartData = [ ... ];

  var seriesData = chartData.map(data => {
    // Calculate data for each series
    // and return series object

    return {
        name: seriesName,
        type: 'bar',
        barGap: "5%",
        label: labelFormat,
        itemStyle: {
          color: "#40698D",
          barBorderRadius: [5, 5, 0, 0]
        },
        data: [ ... ]  // <----- insert chart data here
      }
  });

  // Merge option with series data
  Object.assign(option, { series: seriesData });

  // And initialize chart with complete data
  myChart.setOption(option);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try here.

Comment: It's almost there, but now the problem is the bars, they are getting weird. http://jsfiddle.net/90ojpskn/15/

Comment: Try to use https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pictorialBar.barWidth